# MATLAB Search for Library Locations

Tags: windows, git, matlab, path, directory

With respect to external libraries and File Exchange packages, I'm trying to make my MATLAB code more compatible with the multiple systems I run it on.

For example, let's say I want to run my code on two differently setup Windows systems. The function depends on an external library not located within the current work directory, but rather as shown below:

System 1

```
addpath('C:/SomeFolders/Git/3rdParty/Library')
```

System 2

```
addpath('B:/Git/3rdParty/Library')
```

The current working folder for both would be '.../Git/ProjectFolder'

Is there a way to have MATLAB navigate ("go-up/down") the folder hierarchy levels and search for the desired library?

Cheers,

Comment: I recommend to add this into some sub-directory of Matlab folder, say, .../Matlab/toolbox. After that you can add this into path environmental variable.

Comment: Just clarify, you want to search your file over all HDD\SSD?

Comment: Your question is not clear. How would the algorithm know when to stop going up in the tree and start to go down ? How would it know in what folder to go down first ? Without these information it's hard to answer.

Comment: Yes, we do know the folder-levels difference from the example. From the example, the common root folder for both systems is "Git". Therefore, the function would need a way to find out where "Git" is. The only solution I have is to have this as an input field for the function.

We also know that the current project looking for this Library is also somewhere in "Git". What we need is a method to navigate a given number of levels through the folder hierarchy.